# Angular 2: how to update service variable in a module's component so that the variable in lazy module updates automatically?

Tags: javascript, angular

Below is a link to project on Plunker. where there are two components eager and lazy, also there is shared service which is used on both components.

How to update service variable in a module's component so that the variable in lazy module updates automatically?

```
[Plunker example][1]
[1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/L2ypUQZiltSPXnLlxBoa?p=preview
```

Answer (score 3):

You have this behavior because of child injector created new instance of the service. For creating one instance of the service for application, you should use `.forRoot()` method

```js
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SomeComponent } from './other.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/index'
import { SomeService } from './some.service'; 

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule],
  declarations: [ SomeComponent ],
  exports: [ SomeComponent ]
})
export class OtherModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      // here you put services to share
      providers: [SomeService]
    }
  }
}

// and in AppModule
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, 
    SharedModule, 
    OtherModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [ SomeComponent ],
  exports: [ SomeComponent ]
})
```

It will allow you to use one instance of SomeService in your components.

I've updated your plunker. Pleas, have a look [on changed example](https://plnkr.co/edit/JzZBrBCJNsFw6uJNeLFT?p=preview)

Comment: You save me :) that what I needed @Denis Reshetniak

Comment: Glad, that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using an `Observable`. This observable is stored in your service and other can `subscribe` to this observable. Below is an example in which I have removed the standard Angular stuff to improve readability:

**service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    // BehaviorSubject sends last known value when someone subscribes. 
    public isAuthenticated$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    changeAuthenticated() {
       // broadcast true to all subscribers
       this.isAuthenticated$.next(true);
    }

}
```

**component.ts**

```
myService.isAuthenticated$.subscribe(authenticated => {

    if (authenticated) {
        // do stuff
    }

});
```

So when `isAuthenticated$` inside MyService is changed it fires to all subscribers. Please not it doesn't fire if there are no subscribers.

More info about Observables: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html

Comment: I am calling "changeAuthenticated()" but "if (authenticated) {}" condition does not do anything.

Comment: this example works only one module. but lazy module and it's components can't get info from other comonents :(